# Laravel loop running into memory issues

Tags: laravel

I have a custom artisan command that has:

```
public function handle()
{
  while(true)
  {
    $controller = new MyController;
    $controller->myFunction();
  }
}
```

I know this is hacky, but after trying a few things and finding some answers here it seems the best way to achieve my goal. I can't use cronjobs or scheduling as `myFunction` could run for 1s up to 15s, and I want it to run continuously.

The problem with the above is that I run into memory issues. I've already set `memory_limit=1024M`, but that doesn't resolve the issue.

`myFunction` is quite large and it's a trading bot that I don't want to post here, but I'm wondering if there are any ways of 'clearing things' up (that's about as far as my knowledge goes... ;-)). I don't need/want things to accumulate in the memory, everything can be cleared after every loop.

Is instantiating a new controller clogging the memory? Anything else in a loop that could clog memory? Are there ways in Laravel to clear 'everything'?

**Update**

I've added `$controller = NULL;` in the loop, and I'm logging memory usage with by storing the value for `(memory_get_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . ' MB';` in each loop. I can see the memory used is increasing for every loop.

Comment: Move the logic into a job. Dispatch the job. Inside of the job, when it completes, call the job again.

Comment: Would I then dispatch the job inside the custom artisan command in `handle()`?

Comment: Sure. You can do that.

Comment: OK. And then within the job's `handle()` function I would call the job (itself) again? Or is there a better way to create the loop?

Comment: You could dispatch an event from the job when it completes, and add an event listener within Laravel that listens for that event and dispatches the job again.

Comment: I understand. The reason why I’m trying to keep it simple is that in the previous version of the app, that was built on CodeIgniter, I was able to keep running the function. Adding jobs to the queue and repeating them through event listeners sounds elaborate for just running a function continuously, hence my question on clearing the memory.

Comment: Then you can just call `dispatch(Job::class);` once the job ends, from within the same job.